# Changing in app purchase string identifier into an object (deprecated on ios 5)

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, in-app-purchase

i need to change this method of string to an `SKProduct` object, because its' deprecated on my app (ios 5)

(NOTE: this is implemented on the InAppRageIAPHelper class)

```
 - (void)buyProductIdentifier2:(NSString *)productIdentifier {

        srtProduct = [productIdentifier copy];

    NSLog(@"Buying %@...", productIdentifier);

    SKPayment *payment = [SKPayment paymentWithProductIdentifier:productIdentifier];
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];
}
```

then, when you hit buy:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if(alertView.tag == 1)
    {
        NSString *title = [alertView buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];
        if([title isEqualToString:@"Cancel"])
        {
            if ([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(purchaseCancelled)]) {
                [delegate purchaseCancelled];
            }
        }
        else if([title isEqualToString:@"Buy"])
        {
            [self buyProductIdentifier2:srtProduct];
        }
    }
}
```

Can someone explain me what to change?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this link. It provide the sample code that have what u want.
http://www.raywenderlich.com/23266/in-app-purchases-in-ios-6-tutorial-consumables-and-receipt-validation

Find this method in IAPHelper.m
- (void)buyProduct:(SKProduct *)product {

```
NSLog(@"Buying %@...", product.productIdentifier);

SKPayment * payment = [SKPayment paymentWithProduct:product];
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];
```

}

Comment: and what should I put on the : `else if([title isEqualToString:@"Buy"])
        {
            [self buyProductIdentifier2:srtProduct];
        }`

Comment: Change srtProduct from NSString to SKProduct, change also  buyProductIdentifier2: method to `-(void)buyProductIdentifier2:(SKProduct *)product` and inside of it call `[SKPayment paymentWithProduct:]`. Just use SKProduct instead of string identifier.

Comment: I know, I corrected it, thanks; but look at my question and see the alert view, when you click BUY it calls the method. What should I put?

Answer (score 0):

After quick look into [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/RetrievingStoreInformation/RetrievingStoreInformation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH2-SW1): it looks like you have to perform SKProductsRequest with product identifier to fetch SKProduct, then you can proceed with SKPayment

Comment: Yes, I understood that, but I don't know what to change in my methods... I need to fix this today :S

Comment: [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/AddingaStoretoYourApplication/AddingaStoretoYourApplication.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH101-SW1) you have tutorial with code examples, you have to fetch products before calling methods you posted here.